# How to use SpringBoot @ConfigurationProperties with Jasypt in properties located outside application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jasypt

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.2 and use `@ConfigurationProperties` to load my properties to my property bean like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my.prop", locations = "classpath:properties/myprop.properties")
@Configuration
public class MyProp {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    // getters & setters
}
```

Also I have this property file:

```
my.prop.firstName=fede
my.prop.lastName=ENC(MzWi5OXKOja3DwA52Elf23xsBPr4FgMi5cEYTPkDets=)
```

My controller is pretty simple:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private MyProp prop;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String get() {
        System.out.println(String.format("UserConfig - user: %s, lastName: %s", prop.getFirstName(), prop.getLastName()));

        return "something";
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, my properties are loaded and my output is:

```
2016-11-28 14:36:30,402 INFO  9780 --- [qtp792210014-27] c.c.b.m.c.c.MyController         : [OhxxugGR] UserConfig - user: fede, lastName: ENC(MzWi5OXKOja3DwA52Elf23xsBPr4FgMi5cEYTPkDets=)
```

I confirmed that everything works fine and I wanted to use jasypt to encrypt and use my properties, however I added this dependency to the pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

But jasypt is not decrypting as you can see in the logs. I've read the documentation provided in this [jasypt starter](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot) but still no luck.

This is my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEncryptableProperties
public class ServiceBaseApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceBaseApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

After testing what [stephane-nicoll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613628/stephane-nicoll) pointed in his comment, it seems that Jasypt only picks properties located in `application.properties`, so how could I use jasypt with properties located outside this file?

Comment: From the README, seems you are using the first way, but did you config the `jasypt.encryptor.password`, this is not the answer actually, but actually when I want to setup the local but always get the exceptin as `jasypt.encryptor.password` is required, if I set a password, will encounter the `make sure encryption/decryption passwords match` exception.

Comment: @LipingHuang yes I did, anyway I should have received an encryption error if password was wrong

Comment: Don't use `locations`, this attribute is deprecated now. Maybe jasypt only decrypt the properties that are loaded from the usual locations. What happens if you remove the `locations` attribute and put those properties in `application.properties`?

Comment: @StephaneNicoll, you are correct, jasypt decrypts properties located in `application.properties` and not those loaded with `location`. What should I use instead of location if I want to have modular properties? I'm migrating a project composed of modules with more than 300 properties.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue where I was storing my encrypted password in a database and loading that data on startup. But Jasypt cannot decrypt it unless it is in properties file. I had posted the same question to Jasypt guys. Check this link for their reply

https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/issues/31#event-752104289

Finally, this is what I ended up doing.

```
@Configuration
public class JasyptConfig {

    @Value("${jasypt.encryptor.password}")
    public String encryptDecryptKey; // This is the key I used to encrypt my password

    @Bean
    public TextEncryptor createTextDecryptor(){
        BasicTextEncryptor textDecryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
        textDecryptor.setPassword(encryptDecryptKey);
        return textDecryptor;
    }
}
```

And in my class where I had to decrypt, I did this

```
@Component
public class PasswordUtil {
    private final TextEncryptor textDecryptor;

    @Autowired
    public PasswordUtil(final TextEncryptor textDecryptor) {
        this.textDecryptor = textDecryptor;
    }

    public String decrypt(String encryptedText){  // This encryptedText is the one like *ENC(....)*
        return textDecryptor.decrypt(encryptedText);
    }
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Better directly inject the `EncryptablePropertyResolver` and resolve the encrypted key in the setter of the `@Value`:

```
@Autowired
private EncryptablePropertyResolver resolver;

private String yourExternalProperty;

@Value("${your.external.property}")
public void setYourExternalProperty(String value) {
        this.yourExternalProperty = resolver.resolvePropertyValue(value);
}
```

Though I'd be happy if somebody would come up with a more generic solution...